# react-native-walkthrough-tooltip hides keyboard when visible

Tags: react-native, keyboard, tooltip

I'm using this library to create tooltips in my app : `react-native-walkthrough-tooltip`

Now the problem is that whenever this tooltip becomes visible the keyboard hides or dismisses, due to which the tooltip position is wrong.

Any idea how I can fix this issue ?